How to ignore font icon pseudo element conversion in css
Font icons in css are converted to unicode characters
Given css in file
.icon-custom:before {
     content: "\e903";
}

On running vite build, above lines are converted to
.icon-custom:before{content:""}

How to prevent this?
On referring docs, it is implied vite uses esbuild for css minification and setting charset=utf-8 might prevent this issue. But there seems to be no sample config for acheiving this in vite.
Sample Files to reproduce
Project Structure
├── package.json
├── vite.config.js
├── index.html
└── src
    ├── App.vue
    └── main.js

package.json
{
  "name": "vite-project",
  "private": true,
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "type": "module",
  "scripts": {
    "dev": "vite",
    "build": "vite build",
    "preview": "vite preview"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "vue": "^3.4.37"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@vitejs/plugin-vue": "^5.1.2",
    "vite": "^5.4.1"
  }
}

vite.config.js
import { defineConfig } from 'vite'
import vue from '@vitejs/plugin-vue'

export default defineConfig({
  plugins: [vue()],
})

index.html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="app"></div>
    <script type="module" src="/src/main.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>

src/main.js
import { createApp } from 'vue'
import App from './App.vue'

createApp(App).mount('#app')

src/App.vue
<template>Hello World<i class="icon-custom" /></template>

<style>
.icon-custom:before {
     content: "\e903";
}
</style>

Steps to reproduce

npm install
npm run build
check the css in dist folder

